# How to change id depending on location onchange in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I try to create id that is auto generate => XYZ-001. It's auto increment, when the new value added it change to XYZ-002. Now I try to add something, that is when I select location "one" id shows "XYZ-001",  then select location "two" id shows "ABC-001", then I again select location "one" id shows "XYZ-002"(selected location id when value inserted after that id only auto increment).

I could try this way(image)

Controller:

```
public function create() {
        $this->load->model('id_model');
        $assignid = $this->id_model->assign_id();
        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id','ID');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            if($assignid != []){
                
                $last_id=$assignid->buId;
            }else{
                $last_id="";
            }
            if(empty($last_id)){
                $buId = "XYZ-001";
            }else {
                $idd = str_replace("XYZ-","",$last_id);
                $id = str_pad($idd + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $buId = 'XYZ-'.$id;
            }
$this->load->view('test/create', ['id' => $buId]);
} else {
    
    $formArray = array();
    $formArray ['id'] = $this->input->post ('id');
    $formArray ['location'] = $this->input->post ('location');
    $formArray ['created_at'] = date (  'd-m-y H:i:s');
    $this->id_model->create($formArray);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Id created successfully!');
    redirect(base_url().'index.php/test/index');
        }    
    }
```

Model:

```
public function assign_id() {

            $this->db->select('id'); 
            $this->db->order_by('id','desc'); 
            return $clients = $this->db->get('test')->row(); 
        }
```

view:

```
     <div class="row table-1">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="form-label">Location</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="location" id="location" style="height: 60%;">
                        <option value="">--Select location--</option>
                        <option value="one">One</option>
                        <option value="two">Two</option>
                        <option value="three">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="form-label" for="form-label">ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $buId?>" readonly>
                </div>
</div>
```

[image: view]

[image: controller]

[[image: Modelview]

Comment: make snippet of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
------------View--------------------  

<div class="row table-1">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="form-label">Location</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="location" id="location" style="height: 60%;">
                    <option value="">--Select location--</option>
                    <option value="one" selected>One</option>
                    <option value="two">Two</option>
                    <option value="three">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="form-label">ID</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                generateNumber();
            })
    
            $('#location').change(function() {
                generateNumber();
            })
    
            function generateNumber() {
                var location = $('#location').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/getNumber",
                    data: {
                        'location': location
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(res) {
                        $('#id').val(res)
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

------------Controllers-----------
//Please change the model, tables, and fields as per your DB.
//I add a field in the table which is in your location dropdown value. like one, two, three etc.

public function getNumber()
    {
        $this->load->model('users');
        $tps = $this->input->post('location');
        $assignid = $this->users->assign_id($tps);
        if ($assignid != []) {
            $last_id = $assignid->hobby_id;
        } else {
            $last_id = "";
        }
        if (empty($last_id)) {
            $hobby_id = "XYZ-001";
        } else {
            $idd = str_replace("XYZ-", "", $last_id);
            $id = str_pad($idd + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $hobby_id = 'XYZ-' . $id;
        }
        echo json_encode($hobby_id);
        die;
    }

------------- Model -----------------
public function assign_id($tps)
    {
        $this->db->select('count(hobby_id) as hobby_id');
        $this->db->where('tps', "$tps");
        return $clients = $this->db->get('hobbies')->row();
    }

---------My Table ---------------
CREATE TABLE `hobbies` (
  `hobby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tps` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hobbies` (`hobby_id`, `name`, `tps`) VALUES
(1, 'Playing Cricket', 'one'),
(2, 'Watching Movies', 'one'),
(3, 'Listening Songs', 'two');

ALTER TABLE `hobbies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`hobby_id`);

ALTER TABLE `hobbies`
  MODIFY `hobby_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```